# Zend Class issue Upgrade From Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, upgrade, zend-framework, laminas

We are Upgrading Magento Version from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6.

> Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]
> 55% 34 secs 498.0 MiB

**In ClassReader.php line 57:**

```
Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #0 [ <required> Zend\Http\ClientFactory $clientFactory ] of Credova\Financial\Api\RequestAbstract class
```

**In GetParameterClassTrait.php line 34:**

```
Class "Zend\Http\ClientFactory" does not exist
```

setup:di:compile

[image]

**Plase help us how can we fix this issue.**

**Note:-**
We already install `"magento/zendframework1": "^1.15"` in magento 2.4.6. But still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, Zend usage has been deprecated since version `2.4.6`. Therefore, it is necessary to install Laminas instead.

Replace Zend_Http_Client with `\Laminas\Http\Request` (Replace constants from `GET` to `METHOD_GET`, `POST` to `METHOD_POST`)

For example: `\Zend_Http_Client::POST` will be `\Laminas\Http\Request::METHOD_POST` and `\Zend_Http_Client::GET` will be `\Laminas\Http\Request::METHOD_GET`

Replace `Zend_Json` with `\Laminas\Json\Json`

Make sure that you have installed

- laminas/laminas-http
- laminas/laminas-serializer

Here is more infomation:
https://developer-stage.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/backward-incompatible-changes/highlights/?utm_source=store&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=2023-02-magento-2-4-6

Have you any query let me know.

**`Thank you`**

Comment: As per your comment, you mention below thing
Replace Zend_Http_Client with \Laminas\Http\Request (Replace constants from GET to METHOD_GET, POST to METHOD_POST)

Comment: But in my code, we have this "Zend\Http\ClientFactory" class. can you please help on this class?

Comment: On the custom module you used `"Zend\Http\ClientFactory"` please check.

Comment: Check on this module Credova_Financial

Answer (score 0):

The error is from this custom extension.

```
Credova\Financial
```

So here you have 2 options.

1. Install the updated package of the extension which is compitible with magento 2.4.6.
2. Remove that extension and file from the magento 2.4.6.

Now try to run the compile command.